# creating customize listview through arrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Whats wrong in this code..

```
public class MoviesListActivity extends ListActivity {


private ArrayList<Movie> moviesList;
private ArrayAdapter<Movie> moviesAdapter;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.movies_layout);

    moviesList = (ArrayList<Movie>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("movies");

    moviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(this, R.layout.movie_data_row, moviesList);

    setListAdapter(moviesAdapter);

    if (moviesList!=null && !moviesList.isEmpty()) {
        longToast(String.valueOf(moviesList.size()));
        moviesAdapter.clear();
        moviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            for (int i = 0; i < moviesList.size(); i++) {
                moviesAdapter.add(moviesList.get(i)); 

            }

        }

        moviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

after `moviesAdapter.clear();`, `moviesList.size()` become zero. and before clear code movieslist get some data. Now after removing `moviesAdapter.clear()`, application get force close... Pls help..Thanks

Comment: Pasting the relevant excerpt from the crash log would help.

Comment: i want to ask, after moviesAdapter.clear() , why moviesList.size() become zero.

Comment: Try to replace this line : moviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(this, R.layout.movie_data_row, new  ArrayList<Movie>(moviesList));

Comment: You might want to check if the instance onto which `moviesAdapter.clear()` operates upon. I'm having a hunch that your `MoviesAdapter` might be directly referencing your `moviesList`, and therefore the clear is directly affecting your `moviesList`. I'm wondering though, why you're not first setting the data in the adapter before calling `setListAdapter`. Then you wouldn't need 2 moviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged calls.

Comment: there is no any logcat error.. application become force close.. pls help

Comment: you have passed "moviesList" reference to adapter so when you clear adapter data "moviesList" this one also clear.

Comment: Very very thanks Haresh sir... now its working